# ADC Error RSS'ing Efficacy

Tags: analog, adc

Typically... when doing DC ADC error budgets, I've always just done worse case calculations assuming offset error applied, then multiplied by max gain error, and then INL added too... all with temperate drift included as well.

I'm interested in using a less conservative approach, but I want... some justification.

One approach that seems attractive is to RSS different error contributions. But I'm not sure the math or statistical assumptions "check out".

Here are two links that seems to support RSSing the contributions of offset, linearity, and gain errors (after converting to the same units):

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/error-analysis-in-adc-converter-applications/

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/precisionhub/posts/adc-accuracy-part-2-total-unadjusted-error-explained

...

One reservation I have about the method is that it seems like it ignores the interplay between offset and gain errors, since the gain multiplies the offset.

Can anyone comment on this method with any concrete justification, especially with respect to the concern about the multiplicative nature of offset and gain?

Does anyone have knowledge of assumptions that make this method "reasonable" vs "unreasonable" ?